# Update tabBarIcon in navigationOptions using state, not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change the badge of the tabNavigator from navigationOptions dynamically in React Native.

I am trying to change it with setState, but it is not updating.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      postsBadgeCount: 0,
      progressBadgeCount: 0
    };

    this.Apps = this.startApp();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({ progressBadgeCount: this.state.progressBadgeCount + 1 });
      console.log('change state', this.state.progressBadgeCount);
    }, 5000);
  }

  startApp() {
    const BottomNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({ 
      Progress: {
        screen: stack2,
        navigationOptions: { 
          tabBarLabel: 'Progress',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <View>
              <IconFA name="calendar-check-o" size={22} color={tintColor} /> 
              {this.state.progressBadgeCount > 0 ?
              <View style={style.badge}>
                <Text style={style.badgeCount}>1</Text>
              </View> : undefined}
            </View> 
          )
        }
      },
    {
      ...
    });

    const navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
      ...
    );

    return createAppContainer(navigator);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <this.Apps/> 
    );
  }
}
```

When I am trying to update the progressBadgeCount using setState, it doesn't change on UI.

Any suggestions on how to update the badge count in this situation?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`startApp()` is running only once, in the constructor. Rather than saving it into `this.Apps`, you could change your `render()` to:

```js
render() {
  return this.startApp();
}
```

This way it runs `startApp()` on each rerender.

Comment: I tried this. Code is executing, but nothing is displayed. I think it's because it should be like a component <> or something like this.

Comment: I made something similar and solved this problem. However, it seems that this is not the best way to change the badge number at all :|. Basically, it reloads the app when the badge refreshes :|

Comment: I ended up creating a new element just for that tab and it will only refresh the tab component. Thank you